# I receive a lenght of bytes

Tags: java, android, sockets, byte, iso

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

byte[] content = new byte[2048];

int received = in.read(content, 0, content.length);
System.out.println(received);
```

Using this code, I would like to know how I retrieve only the number of bytes that the server sends me.
I was told to use a loop using a Buffer, but as I am new to this area, I didn't quite understand what it means, could someone give me a hand?

Comment: You are storing the number of bytes that the server sends you in the `received` variable - what are you asking really?

Comment: @Joni Sorry I'm very new in the area, the server returns me a specific value of bytes, I would like to know how to read this specific value. Because when declaring 2048 bytes, I get the number of bytes and the rest until I get 2048. However I don't know the number of bytes that the server specifically returns.

Comment: In general, there's no way you can know what the server is going to return before you actually send a request and receive a response. What's the problem with declaring 2048 bytes for the temporary buffer?

Comment: If you do not know at forehand how many bytes the server is gonna send then you have to continue reading until the server closes the connection.

Comment: If you know at forehand how many bytes a server is gonna send you can just read those bytes in a loop.

Comment: We dont know what you know at forehand.

Comment: 030000000300000������������������������������������������������������

Comment: just because the end of the text comes with these characters

Comment: @blackapps - If you do not know at forehand how many bytes the server is gonna send then you have to continue reading until the server closes the connection - ... 
I think that's it, could you show me an example code?

Comment: At the end int received would be -1 then.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the number of bytes that the server sends you in the `received` variable. If you want to convert the data that the server sent into a string for debugging purposes, this is how you can do it:

```
int received = in.read(content, 0, content.length);
String messageFromServer = new String(content, 0, received);
```

Note that in general you need to call `read` multiple times in order to receive all the data from the server, just like with any InputStream. You can find tutorials on using Input and OutputStreams here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html - specific example for reading and writing files, but sockets are no different.
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html - more general and thorough tutorial

Comment: Maybe I didn't know how to explain what I intended at first, but that's exactly it. Thank you very much. rep +

Comment: Incredibly, when making the first call from the server, it returns me exactly what I need without looping the reads. But either way it's good to know if I need to.

Comment: Yes a small amount of data like this is typically sent in a single TCP segment and the operating system delivers it to the application with a single call to read, unless something goes wrong. If you want your application to be reliable, you shouldn't assume this will always be the case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if you found the answer helpful you can mark it as accepted or vote on it

Comment: Yes it helped, but I have less than 15 reputation points for being new, I can't approve the best answer.